# How does parallelization work on async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await

I have the following code, that I intend to run asynchronously. My goal is that `GetPictureForEmployeeAsync()` is called in parallel as many times as needed. I'd like to make sure that 'await' on CreatePicture does not prevent me from doing so.

```
    public Task<Picture[]> GetPictures(IDictionary<string, string> tags)
    {
        var query = documentRepository.GetRepositoryQuery();

        var employees = query.Where(doc => doc.Gender == tags["gender"]);

        return Task.WhenAll(employees.Select(employee => GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(employee, tags)));
    }

    private Task<Picture> GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(Employee employee, IDictionary<string, string> tags)
    {
        var base64PictureTask = blobRepository.GetBase64PictureAsync(employee.ID.ToString());
        var documentTask = documentRepository.GetItemAsync(employee.ID.ToString());
        return CreatePicture(tags, base64PictureTask, documentTask);
    }

    private static async Task<Picture> CreatePicture(IDictionary<string, string> tags, Task<string> base64PictureTask, Task<Employee> documentTask)
    {
        var document = await documentTask;

        return new Picture
        {
            EmployeeID = document.ID,
            Data = await base64PictureTask,
            ID = document.ID.ToString(),
            Tags = tags,
        };
    }
```

If I understand it correctly, `Task.WhenAll()` is not affected by the two awaited tasks inside `CreatePicture()` because `GetPictureForEmployeeAsync()` is not awaited. Am I right about this? If not, how should I restructure the code to achieve what I want?

Comment: _"Task.WhenAll is not affected"_ -- affected in what way? It's certainly affected in the sense that each task passed to `WhenAll()` will ultimately complete when each of the individual awaited tasks completed. The implementation you have seems reasonable (notwithstanding compile-time errors); the `GetPictureForEmployee()` method returns the task returned by `CreatePicture()`, you create a number of these tasks by virtue of the `Select()` projecting your input data to these tasks, and then you asynchronously wait for all such tasks to complete.

Comment: All that said, ultimately it's not really clear what you're asking. Parallelization works fine with async/await when done correctly, and poorly when not. Just like anything else. Async/await isn't really about parallelization per se. It can be used in such contexts, but it's really a more general concept for use with _any_ asynchronous completion of work, whether that involves concurrent processing of some collection of work or a single asynchronous operation.

Comment: This looks like a case for TPL DataFlow, or RX

Comment: I suggest that you follow the convention of suffixing the names of task-returning methods with `Async`.

Comment: In case you need to throttle the parallel execution without resorting to exotic solutions (TPL DataFlow, Reactive Extensions), these two links could be helpful: [Approaches for throttling asynchronous methods in C#](https://blog.briandrupieski.com/throttling-asynchronous-methods-in-csharp), [Implementing a simple ForEachAsync, part 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/)

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I was asking exactly what you said in the first comment. It made sense to me that this was the case but was not 100% sure of the workings of WhenAll. Could you post this as a reply so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to make sure that 'await' on CreatePicture does not prevent me from doing so.

It doesn't.

> If I understand it correctly, Task.WhenAll() is not affected by the two awaited tasks inside CreatePicture() because GetPictureForEmployeeAsync() is not awaited. Am I right about this?

Yes and no. The `WhenAll` isn't limited in any way by the awaited tasks in `CreatePicture`, but that has nothing to do with whether `GetPictureForEmployeeAsync` is awaited or not. These two lines of code are equivalent in terms of behavior:

```
return Task.WhenAll(employees.Select(employee => GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(employee, tags)));
return Task.WhenAll(employees.Select(async employee => await GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(employee, tags)));
```

I recommend reading my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) to get a good understanding of how `async` and `await` work with tasks.

Also, since `GetPictures` has non-trivial logic (`GetRepositoryQuery` and evaluating `tags["gender"]`), I [recommend using `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) for `GetPictures`, as such:

```
public async Task<Picture[]> GetPictures(IDictionary<string, string> tags)
{
  var query = documentRepository.GetRepositoryQuery();
  var employees = query.Where(doc => doc.Gender == tags["gender"]);
  var tasks = employees.Select(employee => GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(employee, tags)).ToList();

  return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

As a final note, you may find your code cleaner if you don't pass around "tasks meant to be awaited" - instead, `await` them first and pass their result values:

```
async Task<Picture> GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(Employee employee, IDictionary<string, string> tags)
{
  var base64PictureTask = blobRepository.GetBase64PictureAsync(employee.ID.ToString());
  var documentTask = documentRepository.GetItemAsync(employee.ID.ToString());
  await Task.WhenAll(base64PictureTask, documentTask);
  return CreatePicture(tags, await base64PictureTask, await documentTask);
}

static Picture CreatePicture(IDictionary<string, string> tags, string base64Picture, Employee document)
{
  return new Picture
  {
    EmployeeID = document.ID,
    Data = base64Picture,
    ID = document.ID.ToString(),
    Tags = tags,
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I'd like to ask a further question. When calling CreatePicture() you await for the tasks that were created before and that are awaited in the previous line. Wouldn't it be safe to use result in this case? Since we know that both tasks are completed.

Comment: @Zalomon: You could. I prefer using `await` because it's more refactor-proof. If the method changes so that the tasks are no longer guaranteed to be completed (with exceptions observed), then the `await` behaves properly.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind about calling an async method is that, as soon as an `await` statement is reached inside that method, control **immediately** goes back to the code that invoked the async method -- no matter where the await statement happens to be in the method.  With a 'normal' method, control doesn't go back to the code that invokes that method until the end of that method is reached.

So in your case, you can do the following:

```cs
private async Task<Picture> GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(Employee employee, IDictionary<string, string> tags)
    {
        // As soon as we get here, control immediately goes back to the GetPictures
        //   method -- no need to store the task in a variable and await it within
        //   CreatePicture as you were doing
        var picture = await blobRepository.GetBase64PictureAsync(employee.ID.ToString());
        var document = await documentRepository.GetItemAsync(employee.ID.ToString());
        return CreatePicture(tags, picture, document);
    }
```

Because the first line of code in GetPictureForEmployeeAsync has an `await`, control will immediately go right back to this line...

```cs
return Task.WhenAll(employees.Select(employee => GetPictureForEmployeeAsync(employee, tags)));
```

...as soon as it is invoked. This will have the effect of all of the employee items getting processed in parallel (well, sort of -- the number of threads that will be allotted to your application will be limited).

As an additional word of advice, if this application is hitting a database or web service to get the pictures or documents, this code will likely cause you issues with running out of available connections.  If this is the case, consider using `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel` and setting the maximum degree of parallelism, or use `SemaphoreSlim` to control the number of connections used simultaneously.

Comment: Note that your proposed alternative has significantly, and frankly negatively, changed the semantics of the OP's code. In particular, while the original code was performing the picture and document retrieval concurrently, your version serializes these operations, which is likely to lead to poor performance, and increased latency from the user's point of view.

Comment: @PeterDuniho from what I can see the original code serializes the two operations too (because of the two `await` inside `CreatePicture`).

Comment: You forgot the `async` in the signature of `GetPictureForEmployeeAsync`.
Also about the *limited number of allotted threads*, we have no idea about the inner workings of the async methods `GetBase64PictureAsync` and `GetItemAsync`. My guess is that probably [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: @Byron: _"the original code serializes the two operations"_ -- no. The `await`s do not serialize the operations, because the second task has already started before the first `await` is reached. In your code, the second task won't even _start_ until the first `await` completes. It's very different.

Comment: A couple of things @PeterDuniho: With respect to *"the original code serializes the two operations"* -- I didn't say that. Also bear in mind that the OP sought better understanding into how his async methods operate, which I provided. OP can use those principles to solve his problem as best he sees fit. Also, you **may have** made a valid point on how my example could be improved, but because none of us know what 2 crucial methods here are doing under the hood, we can't say for sure.  This is not a 'just-paste-my-code' kind of answer, as the last part of my answer indicates.

Comment: Byron: _"I didn't say that"_ -- sorry, you're right. My comment should have been addressed to @Theodor. Still, the change in semantics between the OP's code and your answer is IMHO something that at the very least should be called out explicitly, with an explanation as to why you feel the change is justified, and probably should be avoided altogether.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are right, my mistake. It is easy to get it wrong when you are low on coffee. 

Comment: There are a number of errors, mostly small, in this answer. I don't mean to be nit-picky, but it is important to explain *truths* when trying to explain how this stuff works to people who do not understand it, because there are subtleties that you sometimes need to appreciate.

Comment: For example "as soon as an await statement is reached inside that method, control immediately goes back to the code that invoked the async method" no, that's not true. If the task has *already completed normally* then the result is fetched and the coroutine does not yield. If the task has *already completed abnormally* then there is no yield; rather, the exception handling mechanism is invoked. Only if the task is incomplete does the current workflow yield to its caller.

Comment: For example "With a 'normal' method, control doesn't go back to the code that invokes that method until the end of that method is reached." I see what you're getting at, but be precise. In a normal method -- that is, not an async method or an iterator block -- control returns to the caller normally when either the end of the method is reached or the end of a return statement is reached, and control returns abnormally when the end of something that throws an exception not caught by the method is reached, unless there is a finally... and so on.

Comment: "This will have the effect of all of the employee items getting processed in parallel" there need not be any thread parallelism whatsoever if the task is IO bound. IO bound async tasks run at a level *below* that of OS threads; any parallelism in them is the result of low-level hardware, not high-level operating system structures such as threads. I would not recommend attempting to use parallelism settings to control connection gating, as the connections might happen all on the same thread!